# Erro no calculo de média de um registro de alunos

Tags: c, array, c++, struct, tipagem

```
printf("Nota 1: ");
scanf("%.1f", &alu[n].not1);

printf("Nota 2: ");
scanf("%.1f", &alu[n].not2);
alu[n].media = (alu[n].not1+alu[n].not2)/2; // o erro acontece NESSA LINHA
```

> invalid operands to binary + (have 'float *' and 'float *')

Sempre me aparece erro na linha destacada com comentário, alguém sabe me dizer por que ?

Comment: Como está definida a estrutura da variável `alu`?

Comment: typedef struct
{
    int matricula[10];
    char nome[80];
    int datanasc[8];
    float not1[3];
    float not2[3];
 float media[3];
    Data aniv;
} Alunos;

Comment: Por que nota1, nota2 e média são vetores?

Comment: Sinceramente também não sei , eu estou fazendo este trabalho em conjunto com um colega de turma e ele me mandou a parte dele assim :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muda estrutura para isto que deve resolver:

```
typedef struct {
    int matricula;
    char nome[80];
    int datanasc;
    float not1;
    float not2;
    float media;
    Data aniv;
} Alunos;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/ScalarComposite.c)

Só a *string* precisa ser um *array* de caracteres. Do jeito que estava tinha 3 notas de cada, que não parece que é o que deseja. Entendi que queria que tivesse 3 dígitos. Um número de ponto flutuante tem um formato próprio e você não controla o tamanho dele. O que poderá fazer depois é limitar a representação textual do número para apresentar só o que deseja.

Eu acho que ainda pode ter outros problemas aí, como a data de nascimento ser um inteiro, mas você é quem sabe o que está fazendo. Espero que exista e saiba lidar com o tipo `Data`. Além de ser esquisito ter data de nascimento e aniversário.

Comment: Realmente o erro foi resolvido , só que agora a variável da media não ta recebendo calculo mas muito obrigado :)

Comment: Aí é outro problema, eu imagino que tenha vários no código mesmo.

Comment: Sim,sim :/, é um trabalho em dupla e ele me enviou a parte dele assim, vou ter que rever tudo mas obrigado, me ajudou muito :)